# MLPClassifier parameter setting

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm developing a project which uses Backpropation algorithm. So I'm learning Backpropagation algorithm in scikit-learn.

```
mlp = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(hiddenLayerSize,), solver='lbfgs', learning_rate='constant',learning_rate_init=0.001, max_iter=100000, random_state=1)
```

There are different solver options as lbfgs, adam and sgd and also activation options. Are there any best practices about which option should be used for backpropagation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solver is the argument to set the  optimization algorithm here. In general setting `sgd (stochastic gradient descent)` works best, also it achieves faster convergence. While using `sgd` you apart from setting the `learning_rate` you also need to set the `momentum` argument (default value =0.9 works).

activation functions option is for, to introduce non-linearity of the model, if your model has many layers you have to use activation function such as `relu (rectified linear unit)` to introduce no-linearity, else using multiple layers become useless. `relu` is the most simplest and most useful activation function.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to consider is that the learning rate should not be too large when the activation function is ReLu.

[image]

The main issue with the ReLu function is the so called 'Dying Relu' problem. A neuron is considered dead when it is stuck in the negative side and it is most likely to occur when the learning rate is too large.